# Questions on recommendation box and like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

We have been using the Recommendations Plugin for close to a year but in the past few weeks we have been noticing that the plugin does not display any content. Instead, it displays the following error:
No recommendations for this website yet.
Put some like buttons on your website to engage your users. Details can be found here.

But sometimes, it appears again(just 1 or2 recommendations with no thumb nail-images in chrome but no data in I.E, it still has some problem. in the past, 6~7 recommendations were showed steadily.)

the number of recommendations that is displayed looks like keep changing on and off.

please resolve this problem asap you can.:).

Steps to Reproduce: 1.please Vistit the URL 
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations.php?site=http%3A%2F%2Ffb.sec.samsung.com&width=296&height=395&
header=false&colorscheme=light&border_color=%23ffffff

---

Expected Behavior: Recommendations should be displayed more than 6~7 and thumbnails also.

for example,
here is another URL that is using facebook social plug-in with no probelem on our another site,its normal,and should be like this

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations.php?site=http%3A%2F%2Ffb.sg.samsung.com&width=296&height=395&header=false&colorscheme=light&border_color=%23ffffff

just refer to this. 
Actual Behavior: no data on I.E

1 or 2 recommendation on chrome.

it's showed differently everytime .

---

API/SDK: Social Plugins 
App IDs: 422701287825347 (newworld)

PS: this is temporary app_id to report this. I just know app_id

real App_ID about this matter is 144651938879532.(it will take time to get account ID to create this App_ID, Do I need it)

Answer (score 1):

Clean up your question, it's difficult to read.

You need a client_id or app_id if the recommend box is on a domain other than the one it's recommending. See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/)

Comment: hi,I have some question about this. I reported this problem on www.developer.facebook.com bug report. but I did it on my own account(not account that create app_id).  I know what app_id is but not client ID. is the client_id same as account id that create app at www.developers.facebook.com? plz let me know, I am so confused thanks :)